# Parse XX:XX as time in Power Query

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am very new to Excel Power Query.
I am getting this error:

```
Expression.Error: We couldn't parse the input provided as a Time value.
Details:
    XX:XX
```

So the source is an excel. In the excel, that column contains formulas that grabs cell input from different sheet. They are all time (hh:mm).
If something is incorrect, we just overwrite that cell formula with plain text. In this case it was `XX:XX`, hence the error now in power query.

My question is, can I somehow still make it visible as `XX:XX` in Power Query.

[This is the error I get now. with how it looks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHptu.png)

I tried replacing error with something else, but it needs a time format.
I can trick it by replacing errors with `00:00` than change to formula that does this with `XX:XX`. That seems to work, but it wont copy this info to the table in Excel, it will still be empty.

[Empty cell in excel table with PQ as source.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTH06.png)

Thank you!

Comment: That's not a time value, so you can't convert the column to a time data type if you want that to be preserved.

Comment: @Rory I figured that. So I tried parsing it as text, but that gives values with dates in front of the time, while the source only has time values.

Comment: Why can't you just leave the field type as Any?

Comment: Hm, haven't thought of that. How do I do that, I do not see it in the list of `Data Type` in the home tab.

Comment: Just don't include it in any type change statement, or use `type any`

Comment: Ok I tried `type any` and that gives the data and time in the cells.
https://imgur.com/a/edaLWAQ

Comment: In that case try converting to time, then create an additional custom column (of type any)that references that field and replaces errors like: `try [field name] otherwise "XX:XX"`

Comment: Ah, when it is saved and loaded into the table in excel with `type any`, it won't include those dates. Guess this will do then! Thank you for helping out @Rory!